# What does this expression mean in this context?

Tags: grammar, particle-の

For full context, see here:

https://www.docdroid.net/dEbqqGI/img-20170816-0001-new.pdf

The sentence in question is from line 13-14:

> ほかにいいの、ありませんか。

In context of this dialogue, there's a high amount of uncertainty on my side about the possible meaning of this sentence. xD 

I could imagine that it's something like "Don't you have one which is good besides that/good in other aspects as well." Something along these lines. 
This ほかにいいの is just too cryptic for me...^^

Comment: Where are you getting "in other aspects" from?

Comment: It is a very very creative interpretation of the literal translation I can muster "Besides good (extrapolate copula here), you have one?"

I just cant make any sense of this phrase, so I beat some into it based on the context...I'm basically clueless.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a fun one.  For added context, I read the example that you had from beginning to where you had issues.  I'm going to include the whole quote here just so that we can have be on the same page.

> でも、そのフラット社のは例文が少ないですね。意味の説明だけじゃなくて、例文がたくさん載っているのが欲しいんです。ほかにいいの、ありませんか？

My translation:

> But this dictionary doesn't have very many example sentences.  I want one (a dictionary) that has not just the meaning, but also lots of example sentences as well.  Do you have any other suggestions?

Here's how I broke it down:

**ほかに：** `Other`

**いい：** `good`

**の：** I understood this as a shortened form of のやつ or `thing/unit`

Putting these together, I understood `ほかにいいの、` to mean `other good units.`

**ありませんか：** `Don't you have?`

Literally translated, you have:

> Don't you have any other good units?

It makes sense in context, but I think that a better translation is either what I had above, or this:

> Do you have any other good units that would fit my needs?

Answer (score 2):

The first half of your guess is pretty much correct.
I can also see the implied "in other aspects" since the flow suggests he wants something with better examples.

I might make a direct translation to "Do you have any other (product) suggestions?"